# Flex mobile for iPad Retina

Tags: ios, ipad, apache-flex, retina-display, flex-mobile

I have some trouble with Retina iPad and Flex mobile framework. When i launch application on iPad 2 all works good. But on iPad Retina i have wrong layout. I've tried cheat with DPI(http://forums.adobe.com/thread/977263). Flex components looks good, but native components (StageWebView, StageText) are still on wrong positions. Also, I thought that this problem is solved in a new Flex sdk (4.10). I've tried it. But there is no any changes. How do you solve this problem?

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

In your-app.xml do you have something like:

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

?

Comment: Then you need to show the code, like what values you use for layouting: `width`, `stage.stageWidth`, `systemManager.screen.width`, etc.

Comment: I use scale layout. It looks like that `<s:Group width="100%" top="50" bottom="20">.`

I've fixed my problem by this horrible code:
`var t:Number = 1;
      if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.runtimeDPI == DPIClassification.DPI_320){
  t = 2;
}
      this.stageView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024*t,768*t)`